# In encoder-decoder structure with LSTM , my system trains well but my prediction is not accurate

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am coding to read a sequence of time series with 39 features and want to predict two parameters.
my system trains with 99% accuracy and low validation lost but my prediction is not accurate.
Do you have any suggestion or solution?

Comment: In order for anyone to offer suggestions, I think it would be helpful if you try to describe your model; how your data looks like; the metrics that you care about; what metrics are you tracking in training / validation.

Comment: You need to first analyze whether the performance drop is due to some obvious problems like the domain difference or mismatched training and testing settings.

Comment: thank you, guys. sorry, I am new in this area and this is my first question in StackOverflow. I have time series data. it is an encoder-decoder structure with 128 LSTM in the encoder and 128 LSTM cell in Decoder. I am using RMSE for calculating error and I check test, validation and train data.